# Is it possible to bundle scripts and styles per page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

Although bundling is a neat feature of VS, sometimes I want to have a script or css to be available to a particular page. This way, I can make sure that name conflicts and/or overrides will be avoided.

Is it possible to bundle files so that only global and page specific files are available?

So for example, say I have a page called `Cabinet.cshtml`. And I also have `Cabinet.js` and `Cabinet.css` files. On the other hand I have another page called `AdminPanle.cshtml` with files `admin.js` and `admin.css`.

Now, I would like these two views to have access only to their corresponding files and also jQuery and jQuery ui. So jQuery must be global.

Comment: You can always create your own bundles - `new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/cabinet")` etc which include `jquery`, `jquery-ui` and `cabinet` and include `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/cabinet")` in your view. Or just create the bundle with `cabinet` only and have the main bundle in your layout and the specific bundle in your page

Comment: Oh, that's great. Having `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/cabinet")` in only Cabinet.cshtml file will solve the problem. Thanks Stephen.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So what's the problem? By default in your `BundleConfig.cs` you have:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
```

So put this bundles in your head of your `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

And create 4 other bundles:

```
//scripts
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/cabinet").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/Cabinet.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/admin").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/admin.js"));
//styles
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/cabinet").Include("~/Content/Cabinet.css"));
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/admin").Include("~/Content/admin.css"));
```

Now you can separate theese scripts and styles and add them only on page that you need.

Also I suppose it's good to define 2 sections in your `_Layout.cshtml` in `head` tag.

```
<head>
    //other scripts and styles here
    @RenderSection("scriptslib", required: false)
    @RenderSection("csslib", required: false)
</head>
```

So now in your Views (`Cabinet.cshtml` and `AdminPanle.cshtml`) you can place your libs where they suppose to be like this:

```
@section scriptslib{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/cabinet")
    }
```

Comment: What I was missing was I forgot that I could Render them separately in particular pages.

Comment: What about `@Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")` inside a `@section` ? I'm trying to do that now and getting `<link href="/bundles/css" rel="stylesheet"/>` :facepalm: